# Forcing php to download a file inside zip

Tags: php, image, zip, download

I have a file image.php that dynamically views an image inside a Zip folder. 
So **image.php?location=./folder/Hi.zip&file=image.jpg views the image.**

I have another file downloadfile.php that forces download of file specified in the parametes.
**downloadfile.php?location=.folder/&file=image.jpg* downloads the image***

What I need is to download the dynamically generated image (by image.php) using downloadfile.php.

downloadfile.php

```
<?php
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
$file=$_GET['file'];$ext=$_GET['ext'];$location=$_GET['location'];
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
header('Content-type:"'.$ext.'"');
readfile("$location"."$file");
?>
```

image.php

```
<?php
function showimage($zip_file,$file_name)
{
    $z=new ZipArchive();
    if($z->open($zip_file)!=true){
        echo "File not found";
        return false;
    }
    $stat=$z->statName($file_name);

    $fp=$z->getStream($file_name);
    if(!$fp){
        echo "Could not load image";
        return false;
    }
    header('Content-Type:image/'.$_GET['type']);
    header('Content-Length:'. $stat['size']);
    fpassthru($fp);
    return true;
}
showimage($_GET['zip'],$_GET['file']);
?>
```

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to force browser to download an image file you can use the code from image.php
and just change the header
from

```
header('Content-Type:image/'.$_GET['type']);
header('Content-Length:'. $stat['size']);
```

to

```
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type:image/'.$_GET['type']);
header('Content-Length: ' . $stat['size']);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $file_name);
```

this will force user to download instead of display an image.